# XML to XML Using XSLT without namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm able to convert One Xml into another when the input xml doesn't have any namespace but I'm not able to get the desired output when the input xml has namespace.

**Input.xml(W/O Namespace)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addressbook>
<address>
<addressee>John Smith</addressee>
<streetaddress>250 18th Ave SE</streetaddress>
<city>Rochester</city>
<state>MN</state>
<postalCode>55902</postalCode>
</address>
<address>
<addressee>Yogesh</addressee>
<streetaddress>Saligramam</streetaddress>
<city>Chennai</city>
<state>TAmil nadu</state>
<postalCode>600026</postalCode>
</address>
</addressbook>
```

**Xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="EmployeeDetail">
<xsl:apply-templates select="addressbook/address"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="addressbook/address">
<xsl:element name="Employee" >
<xsl:value-of select="concat(city,'-',addressee,'-',postalCode)"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output.xml(W/O Namespace)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><EmployeeDetail>
<Employee>Rochester-John Smith-55902</Employee>
<Employee>Chennai-Yogesh-600026</Employee>
</EmployeeDetail>
```

**Input xml (With Namespace)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addressbook xlmns="http:\\abc.com\Buspart">
<address>
<addressee>John Smith</addressee>
<streetaddress>250 18th Ave SE</streetaddress>
<city>Rochester</city>
<state>MN</state>
<postalCode>55902</postalCode>
</address>
<address>
<addressee>Yogesh</addressee>
<streetaddress>Saligramam</streetaddress>
<city>Chennai</city>
<state>TAmil nadu</state>
<postalCode>600026</postalCode>
</address>
</addressbook>
```

**Output.xml for above input(with Namespace)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?></EmployeeDetail>
```

How can I retrieve the result with the above input(which has namespace)?

Comment: search the site for "namespaces, xsl" and you will find a lot of answers.

Comment: You want the same stylesheet to handle both cases? Do you at least know which namespace/s will be used?

Comment: Style sheet can be changed based on our need.
I've given sample namespace as xlmns="http:\\abc.com\Buspart" in the input.xml

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. -- P.S. `xlmns` is not a namespace declaration; `xmlns` is. And `"http:\\abc.com\Buspart"` is not a valid URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSL works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:f="http:\\abc.com\Buspart">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="EmployeeDetail">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/f:addressbook/f:address"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/f:addressbook/f:address">
    <xsl:element name="Employee" >
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(f:city, '-', f:addressee, '-', f:postalCode)"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is because by adding a namespace to the input xml you can no longer refer to an XML element by *local name* alone, but you must also specify the *namespace uri* portion of the path (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Syntax_and_semantics_.28XPath_1.0.29)

BTW, you also have a typo in your input xml: **xlmns** should be **xmlns**.

Output:

```
<EmployeeDetail>
  <Employee>Rochester-John Smith-55902</Employee>
  <Employee>Chennai-Yogesh-600026</Employee>
</EmployeeDetail>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your xpath

```
select="*[local-name(.) ='addressbook']/*[local-name(.)='address']"
```

the full solution :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="EmployeeDetail">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name(.) ='addressbook']/*[local-name(.)='address']" />
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name(.) ='addressbook']/*[local-name(.)='address']">
    <xsl:element name="Employee" >
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(*[local-name(.) ='city'],'-',*[local-name(.)='addressee'],'-',*[local-name(.)='postalCode'])"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Output is `<EmployeeDetail><Employee>--</Employee><Employee>--</Employee></EmployeeDetail>` - your sample also needs to include the same changes to the values in the value-of select path

Comment: have to change all selectors to *[local-name(.)='element'] format to make your templates match only based on local names

Comment: If you post a complete solution (complete xsl) I'll upvote it - this is a superior solution to mine as it will work with any namespace on the input.

Comment: Yes, so I am saying please post the complete solution by editing you answer. If you do this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @TomRedfern No, this is not a recommended method, unless you absolutely have no way of knowing the namespace in use. The danger here is unintentionally matching nodes that have the correct name, but are in the wrong namespace. It defeats the very purpose of using a namespace to begin with.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for pointing that out. I can see how that would be a problem. However, it would be a safe approach if you actually knew upfront that your input document would never have nodes with the same name but from different namespaces.